# How do I find the max integer of a string of integer without using a list?

Tags: python

I must use a for loop, no list allowed. May assume string is non-empty. What I have:

```
def max_numbers(s):
    n_string = ''
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            n_string += char
    return max(n_string)

max_numbers('22  53 123 54 243')
5
expected 243
```

Please don't use any advance methods, I am still a beginner. I wanted 243 to show up but ended up with 5 instead.

Comment: Is that `22` separated by 2 spaces with the `53`?

Comment: You're not resetting n_string back to empty when you hit a non-digit; n_string ends up containing *every* digit from the input string.

Comment: Why *not* use a list, or a generator for that matter? `max(int(elem) for elem in '22  53 123 54 243'.split())` works nicely.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You are right, a list or generator is obvious, but the OP is not allowed to use list, and split() creates list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to separate out the integers from the string (as you are already doing, but a bit wrongly), and keep track of the max so far. When a character is not digit, you convert the `n_string` to `int` and compare with `max_` which keeps track of maximum int found so far, and then set `n_string` empty for next number.

The final checking is for the last number, since at the end of the string there may not always be a non-digit, so the last iteration will not be in the `else` part.

```
def max_numbers(s):
    n_string = ''
    max_ = 0
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            n_string += char
        else:
            if n_string and int(n_string) > max_:
                max_ = int(n_string)
            n_string = ''

    if n_string and int(n_string) > max_:
        max_ = int(n_string)

    return max_

print(max_numbers('22  53 123 54 243'))
```

Output:

```
243
```

---

**Edit:**

If `n_string` is empty, `int(n_string)` fails with an error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

So in order to avoid that, a check to see if `n_string` is empty or not is required **before** doing `int(n_string)`. In python, [empty string evaluates to `False`, and non-empty string to `True`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So, simply writing

```
if n_string and int(n_string) > max_:
```

checks if `n_string` is non-empty *and* `n_string` as integer is greater than `max_`. When `n_string` is empty, the second part of the `if` is not evaluated due to [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) behaviour of `if`, thus the error is avoided.

---

Some related links:

- Short-circuit in boolean expressions in python: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)
- Truth value testing in python: [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and [an answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty/34558732#34558732)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Although not as easy to understand as Gordon's answer, I appreciate another point of view. This lets me learn more about what loops can do!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, the one thing I dont understand is what is "n_string and int(n_string)" nesscessary. How come if I removed n_String it doesnt work?

Comment: @Jeffrey Edited the answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to write any code for you because doing it the way you have specified is just boring. Also since you have not indicated what version of python you are using, I will just assume version 2.

Here are a few things you will need:

- [**str.isspace()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) Use this to determine when you have reached a space
- [**str.isdigit()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) Use this to determine when you have read a number
- [**int()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) Use this to convert a string number to integer

### The algorithm goes like this:

1. First initialize a variable called `num` to the empty string
2. Read digits until you either reach the end of the string or reach a non digit. Each digit read should be appended to `num`
3. If you reach a space or end of the string and `neg` is not empty, use `int` to convert `num` to an integer otherwise skip to step 5
4. Compare this value to your current max and replace max with the value if it is larger
5. Repeat from step 1 if you have not reached the end of the string
6. Finally print your current max

### Special case to handle negative numbers

1. Initialize a variable called `num` to the empty string and a variable called `neg` to `1`
2. If the first thing read is not a digit and is not space but is the `-` character, set `neg` to `-1` otherwise read digits until you either reach the end of the string or reach a non digit. Each digit read should be appended to `num`
3. If you reach a space or end of the string and `num` is not empty, use `int` to convert `num` to an integer; otherwise skip to step 6
4. Multiply this integer by `neg`
5. Compare this value to your current max and replace max with the value if it is larger
6. Repeat from step 1 if you have not reached the end of the string
7. Finally print your current max

---

The non boring version:

```
print (max(map(int, my_str.split())))
```

Comment: split counts as a list unfortunately :/

Comment: Why would he need both `isspace()` and `isdigit()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I guess he could do away with isspace

Comment: Upvoted for the step by step explanation, which is a lot more helpful for such beginner OPs.

Answer (score 1):

```
def max_numbers(s):
    # biggest number we've seen so far.  init to a very small number so
    # it will get replaced immediately by real input data
    biggest = -999

    # accumulate digit characters from input
    n_string = ''

    # loop through each input character
    for char in s:

        # is it a digit 0-9?
        if char.isdigit():

            # add it onto the end of n_string
            n_string += char

        # not a digit
        else:

           # if n_string has some digits in it
           if n_string:

                # calculate integer value of n_string, and if it's bigger
                # than the previous biggest, save it as the new biggest
                biggest = max(biggest, int(n_string))

                # reset n_string back to empty
                n_string = ''

    return biggest
```

Comment: A better initial value for `biggest` will be `float('-inf')` or set it to `None` and immediately replace it with the first integer in the string

Comment: THANK YOU! It was a good explanation-easy to understand. It seems that I have to study more on loops! I did not know about the reset method.

Answer (score -2):

If @IvanCai's answer is too advanced try:

```
def max_numbers(s):
    top=0
    curr=0
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            curr*=10
            curr+=int(char)
            if curr>top:
                top=curr
        elif char==' ' or char=='\n':
            curr=0
    return top
print(max_numbers('22 53 123 54 243'))
```

Comment: Code dumps with no explanation are not useful in this context.