# Using the glob module in while loop to wait for a download

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, wait, glob, pause

I want to pause my python script while waiting for a file download to happen.
I don't want to use an explicit wait.
I want this to run fast and not rely on an explicit wait.
I'm kinda noobish but here is what I have tried.

```
file_check = glob.glob1('downloads', '*.pdf')
        while not os.path.isfile(str(file_check)):
            time.sleep(1)
```

I used the str() because it complained about needing a string for the path.
I have a feeling this isn't the way to properly do this. so how should I dynamically wait for a file download?

P.S
My .pdf file downloads into '/downloads', and my pdf is dynamically named before download so that's why I need globs wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `file_check = glob.glob1('downloads', '*.pdf')` the result of `glob.glob1(...)` is stored in `file_check` just once and that's it. In this case, if you enter inside the `while` loop you never will get out of there because `file_check`  will not change (except if there are threads or stuff like that that can modify their value externally).

[glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) and glob.glob1 (this one it's not even public, as you can see the docs) returns a list. If 'downloads' folder it's empty, you will get an empty list  `[]`. In Python, lists have an [implicit booleanness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty), so if the list it's empty, in a conditional statement it will be interpreted as `False`, or 'True' if it's not empty.

Rewriting your code the result will be something like this:

```
while not glob.glob1('downloads', '*.pdf'):
    time.sleep(1)
```