# Use boolean array as condition

Tags: python

I was wondering if you can pass an array of conditions as a condition, specifically in Python?

for example:

```
conditions = [True, False, True, True, False]

if conditions:
    <do stuff>
```

Python doesn't throw an error when I give it something like this, but I'm not sure if it's doing what I want it to do. Is it actually comparing the whole list? And if so, is it in an `and` or `or` fashion? Or is it doing something different, like only comparing the first item?

Comment: It only checks if the list is non-empty.

Comment: Related (and in my opinion a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: Don't mix up the terms "array" and "list".

Comment: Sorry, java background peeking through there (ArrayList)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty lists are "false"; all others are "true". If you want to do stuff if *all* the conditions are true, use

```
if all(conditions):
    <do stuff>
```

If you want to do stuff if *any* of the conditions are true, use

```
if any(conditions):
    <do stuff>
```

Answer (score 2):

A list will pass an if test if it is non empty. So `[]` will be false and all other values will be true for the purposes of the test.

If you want to test if any value of a list is True you can use `any` to do so. If you want to test if all values are true use `all` in the same way.

Example:

```
if any(conditions):
     do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(conditions):
  ...
```

Comment: why -1? My answer wasn't useful..?

Comment: Different people downvote for different reasons such as: incomplete answers, answers without explanation, or even Python 2 links. You can't know for sure \*shrug\*

Comment: They should remember though, that they sacrifice (a bit) their rating as well. I can understand when the question was about python and answer was about Peppa Pig, but here... Doh..

Answer (score 0):

Just use [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> conditions = [True, False, True, True, False]
>>> all(conditions)
False
>>> conditions = [True, True, True, True, True]
>>> all(conditions)
True
>>>
```

From the docs:

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).