# How to use a variable in views.py inside a template in Django?

Tags: django

I have a variable in the file `views.py` of my app directory.
I need to print that variable inside my template.
How can I do That?

Comment: Why Down votes?

Comment: Because this is an absolutely basic question which is answered with a simple read of the tutorial.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty?rq=1) a basic question too. Why then so many upvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variable into context dictionary and render it in the template,

When you use a Django Template, it is compiled once (and only once) and stored for future use, as an optimization. A template can have variable names in double curly braces, such as {{ myvar1 }}, {{ myvar2 }}.

A Context is a dictionary with variable names as the "key" and their values as the "value". Hence if your context for the above template looks like: {myvar1: 101, myvar2: 102}, when you pass this context to the template render method, {{ myvar1 }} would be replaced with 101 and {{ myvar2 }} with 102 in your template. This is a simplistic example, but really a Context object is the "Context" in which the template is being rendered.

As for a ContextProcessor, that is a slightly advanced concept. You can have in your settings.py file listed a few Context Processors which take in an HttpRequest object and return a dictionary (similar to the Context object above). The dictionary (context) returned by the Context Processor is merged into the context passed in by you (the user) by Django.

A use case for a Context Processor is when you always want to insert certain variables inside your template (for example the location of the user could be a candidate). Instead of writing code to insert it in each view, you could simply write a context processor for it and add it to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings in settings.py.

An example,

In your views.py

```
foo = 'bar'
context = {'foo': foo }
return render(request, 'template_name', context)
```

And in your template, you can access the variable,

```
{{ foo }}
```

Comment: Here `bar` is variable name?

Comment: `foo = 'bar'` means foo is the variable name, 'bar' is just a string

Comment: why then `bar`?

Comment: `'bar'` is a string. `foo` is a variable which holds the string value. Then, if you want to print the variable in the template, look at my answer. do what it says.

Comment: @kashish , context = {'foo': foo } you can say this, context = {'foo': 'bar' } he divide it for your understand. because you said its variable thats why

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Thanks for comment. Why string `bar`? Why not something else.

Comment: It could be anything, I said its just an example.... You can change it whatever you please.....

Comment: Always a pleasure, buddy.. Appreciate the support!!

Comment: @FazilZaid How can I handle a list instead of variable?

Comment: you could do the same, pass a context with a dictionary like above.... and loop inside it in the template..