# python if statement on empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

The python `if` statement *can* be used in the following way

```
a = []
if a:
    # do something
```

i.e., the conditional can be an object (in this case a list). In this case, as far as I understand it, the conditional is evaluated by `bool([])` which evaluates to `False`. On the other hand, `bool([1])` evaluates to `True` and hence something is done.

I personally like this behaviour - it seems clear, but colleagues have pointed out it is unclear.

Is this recommended? What are the potential gotcha's? Is it pythonic or should something more explicit be done?

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: The type of `a` is generally not guaranteed when it's evaluated like that. Using an if like that is generally the most pythonic way because it can handle any input. On the other hand, everything is context dependent and asking for general opinions like this will just mess you up in the long run.

Comment: One minor annoyance I have encountered with this idiom is that some times users use list and Numpy arrays interchangeably and this breaks when `a` is a Numpy array with more than 1 element.

Comment: Wait...I didn't mark this as a duplicate. It is not a duplicate of what's been listed. I marked it as opinion based. Don't lie about me, SO!

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the input. Agreed it is opinion-based. But, this is not a duplicate of that question.