# Count number of empty array occurrences within a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to count the number of occurrences of an empty array within a 2D array in the most efficient manner. For example :

```
array = [[a,b],[a,b,c],[a],[],[],[],[]]
```

The answer I would like to get should be `4`.

How do we get around doing that without using a lengthy for loop process? It shouldn't also use Numpy, just plain simple Python. I tried .count, but I doesn't quite work with empty arrays.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: @cryptonome Doesn't exactly quite address my problem being it a 2D array and counting each empty array in a easy manner.

Comment: This is a `list` not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my short solution using the `list.count()` method:

```
array = [[a,b],[a,b,c],[a],[],[],[],[]]

print(array.count([])) # 4
```

Comment: damn, this is better

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [[a,b],[a,b,c],[a],[],[],[],[]]
answer = len([a for a in array if not a])

>>> answer
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1],[],[],[],[]]

print(sum(1 for arr in array if not arr)) # 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `array.count([])` method but just introducing an option that has not been displayed

```
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x == [], array))))
# 4
```