# How to filter rows containing empty lists in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
A    B    C    D
foo  foo  foo  ['list_value']
bar  bar  bar  ['list_value', 'another_list_value']
baz  baz  baz  []
```

How can I filter out the empty list? I'm trying `.isin` but it throws me an error:

```
df[df['D'].isin([])]

SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0000017ECA74BF30> returned a result with an error set
```

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty) question but couldn't figure out how to implement in a DataFrame context.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert lists to boolean by `astype`, empty lists return `False`s, so filtering working nice:

```
df1 = df[df['D'].astype(bool)]
print (df1)
     A    B    C                                 D
0  foo  foo  foo                      [list_value]
1  bar  bar  bar  [list_value, another_list_value]
```

Another solution is filter by length with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) - it working with all iterables:

```
df1 = df[df['D'].str.len() != 0]
```