# How can I simplify this for a PyCharm tutorial code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing some tutorials online and I being working with PyCharm, (an excellent IDE btw) but, it shows me that i could simplify a if statement

This is only for my knowledge, nothing more

> if len(tasks) == []:

The suggestion says: Expression can be simplified. This inspection detects equality comparison with a boolean literal.

Comment: your statement can be simplified to `if False` because `len` returns `int` and `[]` is an empty `list`

Answer (score 3):

`len(tasks) == []` will always be `False`; you probably mean `len(tasks) == 0`. which is usually just used as

```
if not tasks:
    do_stuff()
```

the doc on [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) may be helpful.

Comment: You are right that it is usually used as `if tasks:` but checking `if len(tasks) == 0:` is recommended for code clarity.

Comment: PEP8 guide recommends using the falsy-ness of an empty list i.e. `if tasks:`. _For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false._ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51

Comment: @Adirio i disagre... to me `if tasks` looks more *pythonic* (not that this is a well defined term...). where does your recommendation come from? would you have a reference?

Comment: `if tasks:` is more pythonic and is recommended by the PEP8, as @abdusco said (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations, third starting from the bottom). What I meant is that writting `if len(tasks) == 0` is what I recommend to begginers as it is more clear. If you ask about my opinion, that recomendation of PEP8 goes against The Zen Of Python (explicit is better than implicit) (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
if tasks:
    # do something
```

which will evaluate to false if `tasks` list is empty `[]` or is `None`.

---

From PEP8 guide

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51

Answer (score 0):

[len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) is the [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) in Python. This is what documentation explain about [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) functions.

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

So [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function always return an integer value.

```py
>>> _list = []
>>> len(_list)
0  # It's 0, because it's an empty list.
>>> len(_list) == []
False  # Yes, because 0 is not equal to list
>>> 0 == []
False  # Same as before, len(_list) always return 0
```

I think You are check the `list` is empty or not, can do it easily in this way.

```py
if tasks:  # or len(tasks) != 0
    # do something when list has one or more values:
else:
    # do something when list is empty
```

You can refer more about from [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513/6194097) question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not tasks:
   do_stuff()
```

You can directly apply `not` operator on array to check if the array is empty or not.