# Idiomatic way to check if list is none in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The question is not about an empty list [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty)
e.g. I have an object which could be either `list` or `None`
I find a way to create a list from it like

```
maybe_list = _get_list_or_none()
maybe_list = maybe_list if maybe_list else []
```

Maybe you can help me to find a more natural and idiomatic way to do it

Comment: `definitely_list = _get_list_or_none() or []`…?!

Comment: you can check type, you will get answer list or none

Comment: the idiomatic way to check if something is `None` is `if some_object is None`, but your approach already works, and is decently idiomatic