# How to remove all occurrences of an element from list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

```
ls = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2], [2, 3], [], [], [3]]
```

Is there any python list method that will enable me to remove all the similar items at once. For example, I have a 2d list 'ls' which has three empty list items []. I want to remove all the empty list items at once. 
I know it can be done with 'remove' and 'loop.' But is there any method to do the operation at once?
To be simple: I want all the '[]' to be deleted. And thus the answer would be like this.
`[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]`

Comment: You can use `set(ls)` to eliminate duplicate entries. But that would convert the list to a set.

Comment: Set is the answer..

Comment: Do you want to remove only the duplicates or the original item as well? In other words, do you want to remove three 1's or just two?

Comment: @amanb Yeah set do works. list(set(ls)) will also make the set to list again. But I am working with a 2d list. So set won't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the 2d list?

Comment: @amanb `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2], [2, 3], [], [], [3]]`. I was trying to get the subset of of [1, 2, 3].

Comment: @Saykat do you intend to remove the original item as well if it has duplicates?

Comment: @Saykat, okay. The requirement is still not clear. Please update the question as well.

Comment: @Saykat Are you trying to remove all occurrences of a particular element or everything that is not a particular element (like everything that isn't `[1, 2, 3]`)?

Comment: The question is very clear at the moment. Please take time to [edit] the question and add [mcve] so that we can be helpful.

Comment: @illiteratecoder edited the question and hopefully, it is now more clear.

Comment: also similar elements like `[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]` should be removed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `remove_all` method or anything like that, but the best ways to accomplish this are with a list comprehension or `filter`.

Assuming that `ls` only contains other lists you can write the following to remove all occurrences of the empty list `[]`:

### List Comprehension

```
ls = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2], [2, 3], [], [], [3]]
ls = [x for x in ls if x]
# now ls =  [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

### Filter

```
ls = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2], [2, 3], [], [], [3]]
ls = list(filter(None, ls))
# now ls =  [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

### Generalizing for more than just the empty list

If you wanted to remove all occurrences of a given element `elem` (that is not the empty list) you can modify the above code as follows:

```
ls = [x for x in ls if x != elem]

##### or #####

ls = list(filter(lambda x: x != elem, ls))
```

Comment: Yes, you could substitute any other value you want to remove for `1`. But as the question was worded, the desired behavior was to remove all occurrences of one element.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the change in the question

Comment: if you have similar elements like `[[2, 2,2], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [3,3,3]]` ?

Comment: @kederrac While the title of the question might be misleading, the question is asking about removing all occurrences of a specific element, in this case all occurrences of `[]`. I will update my answer to show how to remove all occurrences of any given element though.

Answer (score 0):

A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections module.)

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. But it is specific to this case:

```
ls = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2], [2, 3], [], [], [3]]
[l for l in ls if len(l)!=0]
```

Comment: Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty). `if len(l)!=0` is not recommended and shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` here to remove all the `[]` lists and maintaining the order.

```
list(filter(None,ls))
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

List comprehension of the above would be

```
[lst for lst in ls if lst]
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the followings approaches:

**1)**

```
l = [x for x in ls if x != []]
```

or

```
l = [x for x in ls if x]
```

**2)**

```
l = filter(None, ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `collections.Counter` with the built-in function `filter`:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(map(str, ls))
ls = list(filter(lambda x: count[str(x)] == 1, ls))
ls
```

output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```