# BeautifulSoup find_all with class attributes when attribute missing

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**I will answer my own question:** After writing up the question, I found the answer. The answer was in the docs, but I missed it, so writing it here at *stackoverflow* for reference.

**Question:** If *BeautifulSoup*'s `find_all()` cannot find a particular `class`, why does it not return `None`?

```
html = """
    <div><p class="apple">apple</p></div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
s = '<p class="banana">banana</p>'
p = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'banana'})
print(type(p))
## bs4.element.ResultSet
if p is None:
    print("p is None, as expected")
else:
    s = soup.p.extract()
    print("p is not None... but why?") 
print(s)

## p is not None... but why?
## <p class="apple">apple</p>
```

Comment: The problem was not a subtlety about the class attributes, but simply that `find_all()` returns an empty list rather than `None` (see answer below). In retrospect I could have made a much simpler example, e.g. with an empty string `html = ''` and `soup.find_all('p')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> If `find_all()` can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If `find()`
>   can’t find anything, it returns `None`:

Conclusion: `find()` and `find_all()` behave differently in this respect!

---

In the conditional above,

```
if p is None:
```

may be replaced by:

```
if not p:
```

as explained [here](http://See:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty).