# How to check dictionary without values

Tags: python, dictionary

I declared this dictionary:

```
person ={'name':[],'age':[], 'adress':[]}
```

Is there a function that allows to check if it has values or not? 
 For example:

```
person = { 'name':[], 'age':[], 'adress':[] }
```

--> returns empty and if

```
 person = { 'name':['Paul'], 'age':[25], 'adress':['xxxxx'] }
```

--> returns not empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Comment: Also, you are using `=` when you should be using `==` to test the equality of two values

Comment: I used  =  because I just wanted to explain the situation

Comment: ```any({ 'name':[], 'age':[], 'adress':[]}.values())```

Comment: What should happen if dictionary values are partially empty (for example there is name and address but no age)?

Comment: @scicyb thank you it works for me it is exactly what I want

Comment: @AivarPaalberg it doesn't matter I just want to check if there is value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list will be considered truthy iff it's non-empty.  That is,

```
if []:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

outputs `No`.

There's also the builtin function `any` which takes an iterable as an argument and returns `True` if any of the produced values are truthy.  Therefore, if you want to know if any of the lists contain any values, you could do

```
any(person.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
if all(person.values()):
    # not empty lists
elif not any(person.values()):
    # all empty
else:
    # some empty
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a solution for you, Regards

```
person = { 'name':[], 'age':[], 'adress':[] }

#Logical array
#True: empty fields
#False: Non empty fields
field_empty_list=[]
for field in person.keys():
    field_empty_list.append(not person[field])

# If any field is empty
any_field_is_empty = any(field_empty_list)

# If all keys are empty
all_fields_is_empty = all(field_empty_list)
```