# Find element in a script tag beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to beautiful soup, and I'm trying to find a way to search if an element exists within the script tag, but I keep getting not found when it's clearly there. Can you please help me with what's wrong with my line of code.

```
mykeyword = [element.text for element in soup.find_all("script")]
s = [element.find('cookie.indexOf') for element in mykeyword ]

if  'cookie.indexOf' in s:
    print('exist')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Thanks

Comment: I am confused. `<script>` tags contain code (usually javascript) and not other tags. Can you post a sample of the HTML?

Comment: the [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method returns the index of the found substring (or -1 if it wasn't found).

Comment: Rather than element (which is confusing re html), it looks like you are searching for a substring within a string? Please update the question with the relevant html.

Answer (score 0):

The priblem is that the method [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns the index of the substring in the original string (or `-1` if it's not found) so `s` is just a list of indexes. Instead you might want to do something like:

```py
s = [element for element in mykeyword if 'cookie.indexOf' in element]
```

and then check if the list is empty like this:

```py
if len(s) != 0: print('exist')
else: print('not found')
```

Comment: see [this SO quastion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513/14160477) for other ways to check if a list is empty in python.

Comment: I followed this and I still get the same not found. When i did print the source, I can see that the <script> some text here cookie.indexOf </script> but the s line of code, is not seeing it, and keep returning not found. I was testing for this site theblondeabroad.com

Comment: @Justine try printing `mykeyword` to check if it has the relavent strings. Also, I couldn't find the docs for `.text`, but I did find `.get_text()` and `.string`, maybe those will work.