# why if b(list) = 0 ; print('empty') not working? I was testing something but find out this line not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
if b(list) = 0;
    print('empty');
```

I want to make it to find out if the list is empty but this not working, I am too new for this.
what can I do if I want to know if the list is empty?

Comment: try ```if len(list)==0: print("List is empty.")```

Comment: Yes, the semicolon does not belong in python.

Comment: I recommend looking for existing answers to your question in TackOverflow before posting the question. This a duplicate of the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty 
Also the mentioned code syntax is not correct. For example, to check a coding in `if statement` you must use `==` and not `=`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a list is empty you can use a if check. I am assuming that your empty list is called `empty_list`

```
empty_list = []
if not empty_list:
    print('list is empty')
else:
    print('List contains data')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
list_test=[]
if list_test==[]:  #== Since an empty list is potrayed as [], it check if the list is []
    print("List is empty.")
else:
    print("List is not empty.")
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But please add some text around your code to help the OP understand your answer. This encourages them not to copy/paste the answer. Thank you!